# How do I remove the extension for an external file in my wordpress htaccess file?

Tags: php, wordpress

At the moment I have the following in my wordpress .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've uploaded a separate .php file called contact.php that I'd like to rewrite so that users can access it via http://mydomain.com/contact instead of http://mydomain.com/contact.php

What do I need to put into my .htaccess file so that I can have this rewrite for this **one** file only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one line for your redirect as shown below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]  <-- New Line
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put this before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment, since it's not WP related:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L] # /contact rewrite
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```